# Uncaught TypeError JS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Our jQuery displays following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Code is

```
(function ($) {
            $('.afc_close_content').click(function(){                   
                    var afc_content_id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
                    $('#'+afc_content_id).hide();
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

What about issue in the code.
Issue URL - https://wordpress3.guru99.com/guide-to-install-jmeter.html

Comment: Did you inlcude jQuery?

Comment: With WordPress, you need to start with `jQuery(function($){ });`. Depending on when your script is run and when jQuery is loading, you might still get that error. Make sure your script runs last.

Comment: @Twisty yes, our script Run is last. I have add on jQuery(function($){ }); But getting on same error.